# Check last entry before inserting into DB

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone give me a quick hint on how I can achieve the following:

I have a table with 3 rows: `id` , `value1` and `user`.

let's say there's 1 entry in the DB with the following data:
`1`, `test`, `user1`

Now when I submit my form and before the next thing gets actually inserted, I want to check the value of `user` of the last entry in the DB and change the next entry to either `user1` (if the last one is user2) or `user2` (if the last one is user1)

Edit:

I think I explained it a bit stupid.

Basically I want some kind of Zebra striping for the row `user` if that makes any more sense :-)

Comment: you should have told that 'EDIT' first. This is not the way to go to zebra stripe your table. Just add an `odd` class and `even` class to the rows alternatively when you are displaying the table and style them as you wish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be even easier:

```
SELECT user FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Assuming that id is an AI field.

**EDIT: adding some PHP code:**

```
$getLastUser = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$LastUser = mysql_fetch_array($getLastUser);

$newUser = ($LastUser['user'] == "user1") ? "user2" : "user1";

//insert $newUser to the 'user' field.
```

Comment: Though it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: why downvote? Why not making sense? The solution is simple and combine sql & php as the OP asked for.

Comment: Why does it have to make sense to You @YourCommonSense ? I had a question, Ofir Baruch did post a solution that does exactly what I need.

Comment: @user The whole question doesn't make sense. It seems you are trying to solve some standard problem without proper knowledge, devising something odd and unusable right off your head. In such a case literal answer would be disservice rather than help. Your assumption that rows in the database can have whatever order is a wrong one for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed by executing a query like
`SELECT user FROM table WHERE ID IN(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table)`
and then using that user value to determine what the next user value would be.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid concurrency issues, do it all as one statement:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (value1, user) 
VALUES ('your_value', (CASE (SELECT user FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) WHEN 'user1' THEN 'user2' WHEN 'user2' THEN 'user1' END))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need your Zebra striping at the output, not insert time.